# YouTube Iframe Api Javascript Errors because of loading time

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, youtube

I am currently implementing the Youtube iFrame API into my website. It's all working pretty neet. Everything is working, all functions work but I still get javascript errors.

The functions don't destroy any of the functionality or anything on the website, and all the functions do their jobs. The errors say they don't recognise the YT functions.

Error 1:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDuration' of undefined
```

Code that causes error 1 (endSeconds and startSeconds are correctly defined:

```
var duration = player.getDuration() - (player.getDuration() - endSeconds) - startSeconds;
```

Error 2:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mute' of undefined
```

Code that causes error 1

```
player.mute();
```

getDuration() and mute() are both functions as the API describes, and as I told, the functionality works. So my question is why I get these errors, and I would like some help to fix them.

---

For the context I will include parts of the html & js code down here

HTML

```
<aside class="showcase">
    <div id="player"></div>
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="eq"></div>
        <div class="timebar">
            <div vlass="current_time"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</aside>
```

JS

```
/* Load the player */
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
    var done = false;
    var player;
    var videoId = 'A3PDXmYoF5U';
    var startSeconds = 5;
    var endSeconds = 293;
    var setVolume = 15;
    var suggestedQuality = 'large';
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
          player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height:  ($(window).width() / 16) * 9 + 35,
          width: '100%',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
    }

    function onPlayerReady(evt) {
        player.loadVideoById({'videoId': videoId, 'startSeconds': startSeconds, 'endSeconds': endSeconds, 'suggestedQuality': suggestedQuality });
        evt.target.playVideo();
    }

    /* Soundcheck */
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        var done = false;

        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
            if (player.isMuted()){
                $(".eq").addClass("mute");  
            }

            if (player.getVolume() > setVolume) {
                player.setVolume(setVolume);
            } 
            done = true;
        }

        /* Loop function */
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED && !done) {
            player.seekTo(startSeconds, true);
            done = true;
        }
     }

    /* Reponsive sizes */ 
    $(document).on("ready", function() {
        $(window).on("resize", function() {
            $(".showcase iframe").attr("height", ($(window).width() / 16) * 9 + 35 );

            $(".showcase").css({
                "height": (($(window).width() / 16) * 9 + 35) + "px",
                "max-height": ( $(window).height() + 39 - 26) + "px"
            });

            $(".admin-bar .showcase").css({
                "max-height": ( $(window).height() + 39 - 58) + "px"
            });
        }).trigger("resize")        
    }).trigger("ready")

    /* Timebar */
    window.setInterval(function(){
        var duration = player.getDuration() - (player.getDuration() - endSeconds) - startSeconds;
        var currentTime = player.getCurrentTime() - startSeconds;
        $(".current_time").css({
            "width": ( currentTime / duration ) * 100 + "%"
        });
    }, 100);


    /* Mute button */
    $(".eq").on("click", function(){
        if( $(".eq").hasClass("mute")) {
            player.unMute();
            $(".eq").removeClass("mute");
        } else {
            player.mute();
            $(".eq").addClass("mute");
        }
    }).trigger("click")
```

Comment: Found the answer by accident :) Makes sense, see the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! As the YouTube API sometimes takes a while to load it's functions aren't loaded yet on document.ready.

I trigger the other functions on document.ready of just fire them at the browser right away. Which is sometimes way to early for YouTube's API to load and the functions to be recognises.

Every time the amount of errors are different as well. Sometimes it displays 6 times, sometimes it displays 10 times for example. Which after knowing the above makes sense, as the API is sometimes faster than other times.

Also explains why the functions just work, as eventually the functions WILL be loaded in the browser.

How can I resolve this? Simply by triggering the functions when the Video is loaded, And in the case of my 2 functions (mute button and time bar) when the video starts playing.

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
var done = false;

if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {

    // SOUNDCHECK
    if (player.isMuted() == false){
        $j(".eq").addClass("mute"); 
    }

    if (player.getVolume() > setVolume) {
        player.setVolume(setVolume);
    } 

    // MUTE BUTTON
    $j(".eq").on("click", function(){
        if( $j(".eq").hasClass("mute")) {
            player.unMute();
            $j(".eq").removeClass("mute");
        } else {
            player.mute();
            $j(".eq").addClass("mute");
        }
    }).trigger("click")

    // TIMEBAR
    window.setInterval(function(){
        var duration = player.getDuration() - (player.getDuration() - endSeconds) - startSeconds;
        var currentTime = player.getCurrentTime() - startSeconds;
        $j(".current_time").css({
            "width": ( currentTime / duration ) * 100 + "%"
        });
    }, 100);

    done = true;
}
```

This way there is no risk of not recognising the functions when the API is still loading as the functions won't trigger before the API is correctly loaded into the browser.